# How do I set up a Windows NFS share so that I can view it's contents on Linux?

Tags: nfs, ubuntu-10.04, windows-xp, ibm-midrange

My NFS server is a Windows XP SP3 box with the Microsoft Windows Services for Unix installed.

I have a share configured under C:\NFS with the share name NFS and ANSI encoding.

Anonymous access is enabled, with the anon UID/GID set to 0/0. Additionally, I've set ALL MACHINES to Read-Write, and checked the checkbox to Allow root access.

My first NFS client is a Ubuntu 10.04 box, with nfs-common installed. Running

```
sudo mount -t nfs 1.1.1.1:/NFS /home/user/NFS
```

succeeds, but when I attempt to view the folder (even as root), it tells me that I do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of the folder.

My second NFS client is an IBM iSeries box running OS/400 V5R3. I used the mount command below:

```
MOUNT TYPE(*NFS) MFS('1.1.1.1:/NFS') MNTOVRDIR('/PARENT/NFS') OPTIONS('rw,nosuid,retry=5,rsize=8096,wsize=8096,timeo=20,retrans=2,acregmin=30,acregmax=60,acdirmin=30,acdirmax=60,soft') CODEPAGE(*BINARY *ASCII)
```

which also mounts successfully. Attempting to

```
WRKLNK '/PARENT/NFS'
```

and use Option 5 to enter the directory yields a *Not authorized to object* error - even though I am a security officer with the *ALLOBJ special authority.

My gut says that it's a problem with the Windows share, but I don't know what it could be. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you use simply a *nix box for a nfs server?
Wouldn't be much easier?

Comment: I'm doing some security testing, and it involves situations where the NFS server is on Windows - but I can't break it until I get it working initially!

Believe me, it would be far easier to keep things homogeneous, but that defeats the point in this situation.

Comment: How is the NFS share mounted over the linux box? What does "mount" says? And the logs?

Comment: Not sure what the question is there; I use the mount command specified above, which works successfully. I use Nautilus as root to navigate to the folder that the share was mounted into, which shows an x and a lock icon on it. Attempting to enter the folder gives a permission denied error.

Comment: Almost +1'd your question, and then I saw you were using XP as a server system.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to just use [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) on the *NIX box?  That way you can either access shares on the *NIX box from Windows or mount Windows shares on the *NIX box.

"Microsoft Windows Services for Unix", somehow that gives me heartburn just reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you have the execute permission (in Unix it means "List Folder" when applied to folders) granted on the directory and its subdirectories? There may be some windows specific settings which may be equivalent such as "List Folder" or "Traverse Folder". Grant it to Everyone or whatever NFS server is running as. It does not matter that you are a superuser/QSECOFR on the *client* side, what matters is what the server's account id has permissions to do, what the directory's permissions are, what server user id your client user id is mapped to (in case of id mapping which is not the case here).

Not the case here: Permissions on directories *above* the exported one could also cause similar errors. Example, suppose you had a directory c:\foo\bar\baz exported and all the proper permissions are granted on baz but foo's permissions do not allow the NFS server to reach baz. Error!

Turn on logging on the server if possible and look at the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about with XP.  However, I had a similar issue on Windows Server 2012.
The solution was to enable the **Network Access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users** policy setting under **Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options**.

I found the solution on this page:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh509019%28v=ws.10%29.aspx